# Stopping forced use of OneDrive for Windows 11 Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-11

I bought a 2021 LG Gram which came with Windows 11 Home.

It forced me to use a microsoft account to setup windows 11. I could not find any other way to get through the activation. It looks like they got rid of the option recently.

I activated it with my microsoft account with the intent of removing it after. I signed out of it, made sure OneDrive was not installed (it was not showing up in add/remove programs).

I had created a local user account hoping that by doing that and removing my microsoft account it would revert back to a normal file structure where the Desktop and other folders were all located physically on my computer.

The problem I noticed is that my Desktop, Documents, and a couple other folders are still in a OneDrive folder (C:/Users/username/OneDrive/Desktop). So even though I do not have OneDrive installed it seems to be tightly integrated into Windows 11. Additionally, when I go into C:/Users/ I noticed that the user folder there is still the same folder that existed before I created the "local account" that I was currently logged into. It seems like this whole "local account" is just smoke and mirrors.

**How can I get my Desktop, Documents folder, etc to be not stored on OneDrive?** A lot of tutorials on this assume the desktop version is installed. I do not have it installed on this machine. I want to eventually use OneDrive on a particular folder, I just want to fully control what is being uploaded to the cloud and what is not.

Update:

I installed OneDrive from Microsoft and navigated around and noticed this "Unlink this PC" link that might be a good lead for unlinking the PC.

[image: Screenshot of OneDrive]

Comment: You said "The problem I noticed is that my Desktop, Documents, and a couple other folders are still in a OneDrive folder." Does that mean there's a directory on your hard drive named "OneDrive" and the directories you list are in it, or that you can log in to OneDrive and see your directories, or both?

Comment: There is a folder at C:/Users/username/OneDrive/Desktop.

And this OneDrive folder was uploading to my microsoft account. I signed out of my microsoft account, but its still located under a "OneDrive" folder.

Normally it would be C:/Users/username/Desktop and it would only be located on the PC's harddrive

Comment: You can configure OneDrive to NOT synchronized the folder you have listed and only synchronized your OneDrive folder which can contain as much or little as you want. The option to synchronize those folders are within the OneDrive options

Comment: @MDeBusk To answer your question directly, both of those things are happening. This windows 11 machine does not appear to have a Desktop folder that is divorced from OneDrive.

Comment: @Ramhound I have seen how to do this, but it always assumes that OneDrive desktop is installed on the computer. OneDrive is not installed on my computer. It just seems to be baked into Windows 11. I have looked everywhere on my system to control what folders are synchronized. I could not find anything obvious.
It is weird to me that anything i put physically on my desktop is being synced to OneDrive. I did not set any of this up

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling One Drive in Programs and Features?  That works here (WIN11 Pro).

Comment: Your normal desktop is in `C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop`. Do you have it in there? See also [this link](https://allthings.how/how-to-disable-onedrive-in-windows-11/).

Comment: @John I could only find "Apps & Features" and OneDrive does not show up in it to be removed.

Comment: @harrymc I do not have a Desktop folder in that location. This is where I expected it to be, but it is actually under the OneDrive folder I mentioned in previous comments. I did not move it or do anything to change the setup. This is a fresh install of windows 11 Home.

Comment: It seems odd to me that OneDrive is not installed but your computer is being synced to the service. Have you considered installing OneDrive explicitly and seeing if you can make the changes you want through the UI?

Comment: @harrymc I have checked out that link. Again this assumes the OneDrive app is installed and shows up on the bottom right taskbar corner. It is not there so I cannot log into any sort of settings area for OneDrive.
It seems like it just uses my Microsoft account and automatically virtualizes Desktop, Documents, etc. I did not set any of this up and I did not see anything during the windows 11 setup that stipulated I would be setting this up in any way.

Comment: @MDeBusk I was considering doing this since everything i read online, on superuser, and links even in these comments all assume the app is installed on the computer.
Its just concerning how baked into windows 11 OneDrive is. This forced Cloud usage is so annoying.

Comment: Check the location of your desktop with [this method](https://winaero.com/move-desktop-folder-windows-10/). If required, you could move it to the normal address (ensure your account has full permissions).

Comment: @DeanKnight My only other suggestion is to use Linux, which doesn't play those games with your goodies. That said, there are advantages to having a user profile accessible from pretty much any computer. I just want to be the one to choose how it's done and if it's done.

Comment: By default the location for the desktop folder will be located at *C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop* **unless** the option to synchronize your Desktop is enabled.  This option can be disabled within OneDrive

Comment: @harrymc That method looks like it might be useful for me to move things to where they should be located. I thought the MS Office default to OneDrive when saving was bad enough, guess it will continue to get worse until they force all storage to the cloud.

Comment: If you succeed, let me know and I'll put up an answer.

Comment: You can stop synchronizing your Desktop to your OneDrive account by using the `manage backup` within Microsoft OneDrive settings.  You don't have a Microsoft Account logged in to OneDrive, so your Dekstop isn't being synchronized, you just need to change the location of the Desktop folder using by viewing the properties of Desktop and choosing a new location. **Just to reiterate, your current configuration, is synchronizing NOTHING.** OneDrive is not logged into any account per your screenshot.

Comment: @harrymc That move functionality worked for my Desktop. But when I try to move Documents or Pictures it fails saying there is a folder with the same name already there access is denied. I do not have a folder with the same name located in my user folder I am absolutely sure of that.

Comment: I was able to get Desktop working properly, and I had to go into regedit and edit the values for Documents and Pictures. I made sure they existed in the proper location first and then did a restart. Everything seems to be in the proper spot now. and the Documents and PIctures links under "This PC" work now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summary : After installing Windows 11 with a Microsoft account, the poster
found that OneDrive was very strongly integrated into his setup.
Here is what he had to do:

- Create a local Windows account and disable OneDrive as much as he could
- Move the Desktop folder from OneDrive to `C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop`
  by in the Explorer address bar type `%userprofile%`,
  right-click the Desktop folder and select Properties, and in
  the Location tab, use the Move button.
- For Documents and Pictures, he used `regedit` to modify in
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`
  the values of "Personal" and "My Pictures".

For more information see :

- [How can I move the My Documents and My Pictures folders?](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-and-user-productivity/how-can-i-move-my-documents-and-my-pictures-folders)
- [How to Move the Desktop Folder in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/move-desktop-folder-windows-10/)